# No such file or directory when I try to include OpenNI.h

Tags: c++, linux, compiler-errors, include, raspbian

I'm trying to compile a cpp file, but the compiler can't find the include directory.

I get the error when I do:

```
#include <OpenNI.h>
```

I already installed OpenNI and its dependencies, and I'm working with a RaspberryPi 3, with the Raspbian OS.

What am I missing?

Comment: Well, are you going to (1) state where you installed OpenNI, and (2) show your compile and link command with errors? Or are you going to keep us guessing?

Answer (score 1):

Your missing to tell your compiler where it can find the `OpenNI.h` file.

Find where is `OpenNI.h` installed with:

```
find / -iname OpenNI.h 2> /dev/null
```

Will gives you something like `/path/to/header/OpenNI.h`

Then add this path to your compilation instruction:

```
gcc -I/path/to/header -c file-using-open-ni.c
```

---

You will have the same problem on linking, do the same with file libOpenNI2.so

```
find / -iname OpenNI.h 2> /dev/null
```

gives you `/path/to/library`

you can link with:

```
gcc file-using-open-ni.o  -L /path/to/library -lOpenNI2
```

Comment: I tried that, but I get nothing when I do the  _find_ command.

Comment: Maybe try with `-iname` instead of `-name`: it will ignore file case

Comment: I already managed to figure it out with your suggestions. I was missing some paths, so I added them and it worked. Thanks for your help. @Mathieu